# Analytic continuation of Riemann zeta function using Lerch zeta function.

Tags: riemann-zeta, analytic-continuation

For $x\in\mathbb{R}$, consider the following special case of the Lerch zeta function,

$$
L(s,x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{2\pi i nx}}{n^s}.
$$

The series is absolutely convergent for $Re(s)>1$. If $x\not\in\mathbb{Z}$, then it continues to an entire function. If $x\in\mathbb{Z}$, it reduces to the Riemann zeta function and therefore has a pole at $s=1$.

Consider the following integral,

$$
\int_0^1 L(s,x)L(s,-x)dx.
$$

If $Re(s) > 1$, then the above integral equals $\zeta(2s)$. Now the integrand is an analytic function of $s$ for any value of $x\in(0,1)$. Therefore shouldn't the integral also be an analytic function of $s$, but it clearly isn't. What am I missing here?

Comment: the problem for $0<\Re s \le 1$ where $L$ converges for $x \in (0,1)$ is that the convergence is not uniform there (it diverges as we know at the ends) so the result is not necessarily integrable in $x$ (and of course is not); what you can do is take $\int_{\epsilon}^{1-\epsilon} L(s,x)L(s,-x)dx$ which works by uniform convergence and notice that the limit doesn;t exist for $\Re s \le 1$

Comment: @Conrad, But I am using absolute convergence only for $Re(s) > 1$ and for the other regions, I am using the analytic continuation. The analytic continuation connects the values at $s$ and $1-s$. So, I don't understand how the conditional convergence issue comes up. $L(s,x)$ also satisfies a functional equation involving the Hurwitz zeta functions.

Comment: Why do you assume the integral exists for $\Re s <1$?; For example $e^s/x$ is analytic in $s$ for all $0<x<1$ but its integral in $x$ from $0$ to $1$ doesn't exist because of the divergence at $0$; same here